# set up apache http server in windows as proxy to access another domain

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, proxy, mod-proxy, httpd.conf

I know this should be very basic and simple in theory, but I need to complete this task, I'm new to this and for some reason I can't find a suitable example that works for me.

I am running apache 2.2 in windows 8. I need to access a website, let's call it x.com, through my proxy. The reason is that I need to show it in an iframe and also programmatically log in on it, for which I need to use javascript. This is prevented by cross domain ajax security constraints. By proxying the site I could do that.

I have installed Apache http server. Uncommented the following line

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

in file "httpd.conf" and overwritten file conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf with the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /feature http://x.com/
    ProxyPassReverse /feature https://x.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain x.com localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.localhost">
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted the apache service, now I go to :

```
http://localhost/feature
```

and get

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /feature was not found on this server.

What could be wrong with this set up? Is there something else I need to configure?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the same problem I had, I found the solution.
Simply, you have to uncomment few additional lines in file "httpd.conf":

```
 ...  
 LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so  
 ...  
 LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so  
 ...  
 Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf  
 ...
```

In my case, It worked.